# How to deploy a wordpress site to live server?

Tags: wordpress, deployment

I made the WP site(used OpenServer as a local server) and I'd like to deploy it on a live server.Actually I have already tried it by using a Duplicator plugin for WP, but instead of a real site I saw a WP admin area on the live server. Could you please tell me how to manage it and deploy the real site on the real live server?

Comment: Yes, you saw the admin because you need to complete the set up in the admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend first of all get access to the sql server and save the database by going to PHP my admin > Click on the database from the left hand side > Click export from the top menu > Click Save.

Next get access to the FTP server and get into the public_html folder and download everything to a folder on your local machine.

Then connect to the new server via FTP and upload the contents of your local copy of the website and drag and drop everything into the new server.

While that uploads login to php my admin on the new server and upload the database by going to the import tab from the top menu.

Once imported click on the database and select thee table called 'wp_options' from the left hand side look for the url fields at the top of the list and change them to the new url of the site you are moving to then click return to save the field entry.

Once uploaded go to wp-admin and click on the options tab > permalink structure > click save without changing the options this will rebuild the permalinks to the new url.

You are now done and have migrated well done :)

http://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/